# Find the length of the curve $x =e^{4t}\cos t , y =e^{4t}\sin t$ for $0\leqslant t \leqslant 2$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

> Find the length of the curve given by
>   \begin{cases}
> x(t) = e^{4t}\cos t,\\
> y(t) = e^{4t}\sin t.
> \end{cases}
>   for $0\leqslant t \leqslant 2$.

How do I approach this sort of question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We know that the arc lengths of plane curves $x $ and $y $ when expressed in parametric form as a function of $t$ is given by: $$l = \int_{t_0}^{t_1} \sqrt {(\frac {dx}{dt})^2 + (\frac {dy}{dt})^2} \mathrm {d}t $$

Here $\frac {dx}{dt} = e^{4t}(-\sin t) + 4e^{4t}(\cos t) $ and $\frac {dy}{dt} = e^{4t}(\cos t) + 4e^{4t}(\sin t) $

Thus, $$l = \int_{0}^{2} e^{4t}\sqrt {17} \mathrm {d}t$$ $$ = \frac {\sqrt {17}}{4} (e^8-1) $$

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint.** Use :
$$\ell=\int_0^2\sqrt{\left(\frac{dx}{dt}\right)^2+\left(\frac{dy}{dt}\right)^2}dt$$